# redis pub sub with jedis , sub crashes with error

Tags: java, redis, publish-subscribe, jedis

All

I have installed latest Redis 2.4.16 and trying to use its Pub/Sub system with java. I am putting a message to a channel every second. There is no issue with Publisher but Subscriber crashes with the message

**Exception:**

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / QUIT allowed in this context
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:59)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:66)
at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:131)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getObjectMultiBulkReply(Connection.java:206)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub.process(JedisPubSub.java:88)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPubSub.proceed(JedisPubSub.java:83)
at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.subscribe(Jedis.java:1971)
at com.jedis.test.JedisSub$1.run(JedisSub.java:22)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

***Here is my Code:***

**Publisher:**

```
        final Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");

        ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        newFixedThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    jedis.publish("CC", new Date().toString());
                }

            }
        });
```

**Subscriber:**

```
        JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig,"localhost", 6379, 100);
        final Jedis subscriberJedis = jedisPool.getResource();


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    subscriberJedis.subscribe(new JedisPubSub() …..,"CC");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        jedisPool.returnResource(subscriberJedis);
```

**Pool Configuration:**

```
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    poolConfig.maxActive = 10;
    poolConfig.maxIdle = 5;
    poolConfig.minIdle = 1;
    poolConfig.testOnBorrow = true;
    poolConfig.numTestsPerEvictionRun = 10;
    poolConfig.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000;
    poolConfig.maxWait = 3000;
    poolConfig.whenExhaustedAction = org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.WHEN_EXHAUSTED_FAIL;
```

For installing Redis, I simply used command

```
make PREFIX=/Users/ggg/dev/dist/redis/ install
```

After this I did not use `./install_server.sh`

Jedis version is 2.1.0, platform is Mac OS X.

> Note: What I have noticed is subscriber crashes near about 30 seconds
>   after start.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both the code of the publisher and the subscriber are wrong in their own way.

The error comes from the fact a Redis connection cannot be shared between publishers and subscribers. Actually you need a connection (or a pool of connections) for publishers, and just one dedicated connection for the subscriber thread. Running a single subscriber thread per process is usually enough.

Here, you return the subscriberJedis connection to the pool too early, before the subscriber thread is complete, so the connection is shared.

**In the publisher:**

Since you have a pool of 10 threads, you should not share a unique connection across these threads. This is the perfect place to use the connection pool, and the connections have to be grabbed and released in each thread.

```
    // This should be a global singleton
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig,"localhost", 6379, 100);

    ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    newFixedThreadPool.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
                try {
                   jedis.publish("CC", new Date().toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                   jedisPool.returnResource(jedis);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

**In the subscriber:**

In the subscriber, you need a dedicated connection.

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Jedis subscriberJedis = new Jedis("localhost");
            try {
                subscriberJedis.subscribe(new JedisPubSub() …..,"CC");
            } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

If you need to subscribe to different channels or patterns, it is better to set the other subscriptions in the same thread and for the same connection.

Comment: What is the default size of the jedis pool? I am using a Executor fixed thread pool to with 50 threads.